# january 31 2012 UTC time jump

Tags: actionscript-3, utc

I'm working on a flash project that uses xml-data from a database through php to generate graphs. To draw everything on the right spot I want to convert dates to numbers and I thought Date.UTC(YYYY,MM,DD) was the answer. However for some reason it doesn't convert linearly.
**as3-code:**

```
private function valuedispatcher(e:Event):void {
        debugfield.appendText("succes= "+e.target.data.succes);
        if (e.target.data.succes) {
            var myxml:XML = new XML(e.target.data.xml);
            var mylist:XMLList = new XMLList(myxml.children());
            debugfield.appendText("\nxml[0]= " + mylist[0]);
            debugfield.appendText("\nxml[0].time= "+mylist[0].time);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < mylist.length(); i++) {
                var splitter:Array = String(mylist[i].time).split("-");
                var seconds:Number = Date.UTC(int(splitter[0]),int(splitter[1]),int(splitter[2]),1,0,0,0);
                var ar:Array = [mylist[i].time, seconds, mylist[i].verbruik, mylist[i].corr];
                debugfield.appendText("\nar= "+ar);
                maxtot = Math.max(maxtot,mylist[i].verbruik,mylist[i].corr);
                values.push(ar);
                if(mylist[i].corr!=null){
                    compareNr++;
                    cumul1 += mylist[i + 365].verbruik;
                    cumul2 += mylist[i].corr;
                }   
            }
        }
        else { fakedata();
            debugfield.appendText("\n values= "+values);
        }
}

private function fakedata():void {
        var date: Date = new Date(2012, 01, 28);
        var first:Boolean = true;
        var corr;
        for (var i:int = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
            var dateString:String = "" + date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
            var UTCseconds:Number = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
            var gebr:Number;
            if (first) {
                gebr = Math.round((2.3 + Math.random() * 40) * 1000) / 1000;
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                gebr = Math.round((Math.max(4, Math.min(47, values[i - 1][2] - 5 + Math.random() * 10)))*1000)/1000;
            }
            corr = 10;
            if (i > 134) corr = -1;
            var ar:Array = [dateString, UTCseconds, gebr, corr];
            values.push(ar);
            maxtot = Math.max(maxtot, gebr, corr);
            if(corr!=-1){
                compareNr++;    
            }
            date.date++;
        }
        for (var j:int = 0; j < compareNr; j++) 
        {
            corr = values[j][2] * 0.6 + values[j + 365][2] * 0.4;
            values[j][3] = corr;
            cumul1 += values[j + 365][2];
            cumul2 += values[j][3];
        }
}
```

So the function *fakedata()* is called when I'm operating offline otherwise it should use the xml data.

The problem I now seem to have is that in 'web-mode':
Date.UTC(2012,1,31) = 1330646400000 > Date.UTC(2012,2,1) = 1330560000000
while it is equal to Date.UTC(2012,2,2) = 1330646400000

While in off-line mode the line date.date++ seems to make it go straight from 2012|1|29 to 2012|2|2

What is happening here???

**debugfield output online:**

```
succes= true
xml[0]= <tag>
        <time>2012-01-31</time>
        <verbruik>51.413</verbruik>
        <corr>41.239</corr>
        </tag>
        xml[0].time= 2012-01-31
        ar= 2012-01-31,1330650000000,51.413,41.239
        ar= 2012-02-01,1330563600000,44.178,43.196
        ar= 2012-02-02,1330650000000,24.790,42.459
        ar= 2012-02-03,1330736400000,51.494,57.789
        ar= 2012-02-04,1330822800000,36.498,43.010
        ar= 2012-02-05,1330909200000,32.483,40.951
        ar= 2012-02-06,1330995600000,32.347,31.762
        ar= 2012-02-07,1331082000000,47.655,45.023
        ar= 2012-02-08,1331168400000,44.164,39.372
        ar= 2012-02-09,1331254800000,44.016,52.159
        ar= 2012-02-10,1331341200000,48.150,50.561
        ar= 2012-02-11,1331427600000,59.129,59.882
        ar= 2012-02-12,1331514000000,52.112,43.381
        ar= 2012-02-13,1331600400000,44.064,41.240
        ar= 2012-02-14,1331686800000,47.609,55.833
        ar= 2012-02-15,1331773200000,40.153,55.569
        ar= 2012-02-16,1331859600000,51.860,43.342
        ar= 2012-02-17,1331946000000,40.252,30.049
        ar= 2012-02-18,1332032400000,32.464,26.127
```

**debugfield output offline**

```
succes= undefined
    values= 2012-1-28,1330387200000,36.374,27.516000000000002,2012-1-29,1330473600000,33.566,24.077600000000004,2012-2-1,1330560000000,30.34,23.54,2012-2-2,1330646400000,29.529,21.6454,2012-2-3,1330732800000,29.413,22.931,2012-2-4,1330819200000,30.146,22.745199999999997,2012-2-5,1330905600000,27.961,20.565399999999997,2012-2-6,1330992000000,25.279,20.3054,2012-2-7,1331078400000,25.454,22.2524,2012-2-8,1331164800000,23.905,22.4102,2012-2-9,1331251200000,19.356,20.044400000000003,2012-2-10,1331337600000,18.32,17.900399999999998,2012-2-11,1331424000000,15.984,16.8312,2012-2-12,1331510400000,11.598,14.224400000000001,2012-2-13,1331596800000,13.081,16.643,2012-2-14,1331683200000,13.842,18.5728,2012-2-15,1331769600000,13.669,17.867,2012-2-16,1331856000000,17.472,20.4096,2012-2-17,1331942400000,17.512,18.714,2012-2-18,1332028800000,18.39,18.971200000000003,2012-2-19,1332115200000,21.985,19.235799999999998,2012-2-20,1332201600000,18.049,18.2298,2012-2-21,1332288000000,20.269,18.0362,2012-2-22,1332374400000,19.88,15.9452,2012-2-23,1332460800000,17.259,16.1194,2012-2-24,1332547200000,13.054,14.1248,2012-2-25,1332633600000,8.401,10.4042,2012-2-26,1332720000000,7.112,11.0588,2012-2-27,1332806400000,5.487,9.2158,2012-2-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, an incorrectly read manual. `01` as month is February, not January. To get January, use 0.

[Date() manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#Date%28%29)

Comment: True, now it seems dumb, but it is a bit bizar that 00 as month is january while 00 as date is not the first of the month.

Comment: I agree that this is weird. One explanation for it being so might the fact that you always know a year has 12 months, they cycle again and again. Whereas a month you don't really know, it might be 28, 29, 30, 31 so you kind of define it as it is...